# Is it possible to track how much time I spend in each of the desktops in Mission Control

Tags: desktop, mission-control, time-tracking

I would like to track work time vs. non-work time on my MacBook on a daily basis. I was thinking, maybe if I had one desktop for work and another desktop for non-work, I could more easily track that time. It’s easy enough to switch between desktops with a four-finger swipe.

Ideally, I’d like to check at the end of the day  how much times was spent in each of the two desktops. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: This isn't specific to your need, but what I do to keep a rough track of time while on my mac is to enable the option to announce the time every 15 minutes. With this, you can train yourself to remind you of the time spent on the computer, and to refocus on the important tasks if you got distracted. This can be done through `System Preferences` > `Date & Time` > `Clock` and enabling `Announce the time:` (you can use the drop down menu to set the interval).

Comment: I've been looking for something like this for a loooong time.  I always have at least 4 concurrent projects going at any one time and they each have a dedicated desktop in mission control.  And they all use the same apps.  It would be a breaze to manage time spent on each project if there was just a way to have a time tracker that could measure time on each desktop. I can't believe this hasn't been done already.